# Change params inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update some params:

```
if params[:type] == "4"
  params[:allow] == true
end
```

whereas by default :allow is false:

```
field :allow, :type => Boolean, :default => false
```

this is inside a create Method.

any ideas?

Comment: You're doing two comparisons. The second part should read `params[:allow] = true`

Comment: It also seems rather brittle.

Comment: In general params is your user input. Its not a good idea to change the params.